# Where can I find references of the big classification theorem of unital separable simple nuclear $\mathcal Z$-stable $C^*$-algebra in the UCT class?

Tags: reference-request, c-star-algebras

Theorem(Elliott, Gong, Lin, Niu Tikuisis, White, Winter,...)

Let $A,B$ be simple separable unital nuclear $C^*$-algebras which are $\mathcal Z$-stable and satisfy the UCT. Then $A\simeq B$ if and only if $\text{Ell}(A)\simeq \text{Ell}(B)$.

Comment: I'm no expert in classification, but have you looked at the paper by Tikuisis, White, and Winter?

Comment: I have only found their conjecture about the relation of $\mathcal Z$-stability and nuclear dimension but not their proof...

Comment: I'd recommend starting by looking at the Tikuisis-White-Winter paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.08318) and and going into the tons of papers that are involved in the theorem you are asking about by their references. But if I may ask, what is it exactly that you are trying to find in this?

Comment: Also related: https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.02180